# MySql join returns null on table empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `A` and `B`. I want a query which will return results if any of the values are satisfied in either of the 2 tables. I tried using a join, but it returned `null` when the second table is empty and vice versa.

**Table A**

```
    emp_no emp_add  data
    12      go      nice
```

**Table B**

```
    emp_no emp_add id 
    12      go      1
```

**Required output**

```
    data   id
    nice   1
```

Similarly

**Table A**

```
    emp_no emp_add  data
    12      go      nice
```

**Table B**

```
    emp_no emp_add id
```

**Required output**

```
    data  id
    nice


SELECT A.data, B.id 
FROM   A left join B ON A.emp_no = B.emp_no 
WHERE  A.data='nice' 
AND    a.id='1' ;
```

Comment: in your query you have B.id=1 in the where clause which is restricting the row to be displayed in the result set

Answer (score 1):

use Left Join instead on the table that you accept null values

Comment: its not mandatory that any of the given table have null value either data column can be null  or id column can be null

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select ifnull(a.data,'') as data, ifnull(b.id,'') as id  from tableA a left join tableB b on (a.emp_no=b.emp_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you told that it would happen vice versa, it would better to use [Outer Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in your case:

```
 Select tblA.data,tblB.id from tableA tblA FULL OUTER JOIN tableB tblB on tblA.emp_no=tblB.emp_no
```

Comment: outer join prints null in the field column name while i need null

Comment: Didn't get you...Could u elaborate a bit??

Comment: emp_no can be null in second table so when on statement executes it never satisfy

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN includes all rows from both tables, regardless of whether or not the other table has a matching value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tableA.data, tableB.id from tableA, tableB
```